# How to insert multiple records into Oracle with same timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, date

My question is somewhat different.

People here are asking to insert date along with time, but my question is how to insert only date DD-MM-YYYY ? I do not require time to be inserted. Because of difference in miliseconds I am getting exception. So I want to avoid that.

sysdate,current_time keywords in oracle insert date along with time.

Requirement is like I have to insert 1000 rows where timestamp(I don't want a single millisonds difference) for each row should be same.

Comment: Then why did you tag it with MySQL?

Comment: need to know for MySQL also...

Comment: "What have you tried?"

Comment: Since your requirement was actually how to insert multiple records into Oracle with an identical timestamp, you should probably re-title this question to that extent (so that other users with same concern will find this question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you just want to insert a lot of records with the same timestamp?

First, here's what **doesn't** work:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (tstamp TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (systimestamp);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (systimestamp);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (systimestamp);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (systimestamp);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (systimestamp);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (systimestamp);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (systimestamp);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (systimestamp);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (systimestamp);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (systimestamp);

SELECT tstamp FROM test_table;

TSTAMP
----------------------------
06-JUN-14 12.24.28.659493 PM
06-JUN-14 12.24.28.663258 PM
06-JUN-14 12.24.28.666936 PM
06-JUN-14 12.24.28.671949 PM
06-JUN-14 12.24.28.676808 PM
06-JUN-14 12.24.28.680507 PM
06-JUN-14 12.24.28.684501 PM
06-JUN-14 12.24.28.688620 PM
06-JUN-14 12.24.28.694491 PM
06-JUN-14 12.24.28.698288 PM
```

**The solution**, do your INSERTs in a PL/SQL block.  First get the `systimestamp` and store it in a variable, such as  `v_right_now`.  Then you can get all your records to have the exact same date/time.

```
DECLARE
  v_right_now TIMESTAMP := systimestamp;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (v_right_now);
  INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (v_right_now);
  INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (v_right_now);
  INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (v_right_now);
  INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (v_right_now);
  INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (v_right_now);
  INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (v_right_now);
  INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (v_right_now);
  INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (v_right_now);
  INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (v_right_now);
END;
/

SELECT tstamp FROM test_table;

TSTAMP
----------------------------
06-JUN-14 12.24.48.263444 PM
06-JUN-14 12.24.48.263444 PM
06-JUN-14 12.24.48.263444 PM
06-JUN-14 12.24.48.263444 PM
06-JUN-14 12.24.48.263444 PM
06-JUN-14 12.24.48.263444 PM
06-JUN-14 12.24.48.263444 PM
06-JUN-14 12.24.48.263444 PM
06-JUN-14 12.24.48.263444 PM
06-JUN-14 12.24.48.263444 PM
```

Answer (score 5):

In Oracle use a date with time "00:00:00", for example: `trunc(sysdate)`.
There isn't a date-only type (without time).

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:

```
select to_date(sysdate,'DD/MM/YY') FROM DUAL
```

Or:

```
select to_date(column_name,'DD/MM/YYYY') FROM TABLE
```